# fixed image with a "border" around

Tags: html, css

Hey today I tried to code a landing page but I got stuck. I tried to place an image full screen with a "border" of 60px. Now I would like to have the nav-bar on top and some vertical text on left and right around the image. (nav-bar and vertical text in the “border”). How can I do this?

I already know that's not the right way to do.

```
.fullscreen-img {
    background-image: url(../img1);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 50px solid white;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What seems to go wrong? Can we see your HTML, too? A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've got will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? Or did you want the left and right text columns to extend all the way to the top above the header/nav?

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.middle {
  flex: 0 1 80%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hero-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.hero {
  flex: 0 1 80%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="left">
    <p>left text hi</p>
  </section>
  <section class="middle">
    <nav>
      <a>link 1</a>
      <a>link 2</a>
      <a>link 3</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero-container">
      <p class="hero">big image here</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
    <p>Dat right text</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: nice its near what im searching for. yes the left and right text columns have to extend all the way to the top above the header/nav. for the "border" section on the top i have repeat the process like the top?

Comment: Check it out now

Comment: thanks! sorry i meant for the "border" section on bottom i have to repeat the process like the top?

Comment: Yea, you can just add a footer, or as many sections as you'd like, to the middle. I edit answer